# Centering caption in minipage

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, minipage, includegraphics

I have two images in a minipage which are side by side, but their captions get left justified while I would like them to be centred. I've tried various solutions that I've found on here but they don't seem to be working for me. Can anyone advise?

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=3cm]{geometry} % useful for page dimensions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[t][7cm]{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{/Users/bethlong/Documents/University/PhD/Thesis/Figures/APrimeVisibleDecayConstraints.png}
            \caption{Constraints on visible dark\\ photon decays}
            \label{fig:APrimeVisibleDecayConstraints}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[t][7cm]{0.5\textwidth}
            {\centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{/Users/bethlong/Documents/University/PhD/Thesis/Figures/APrimeInvisibleDecayConstraints.png}
            \caption{Constraints on invisible\\ dark photon decays}}
            \label{fig:APrimeInvisibleDecayConstraints}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a compilable minimal reproducible example so we can if your class and package might be compatible with the caption package?

Comment: Did you try adding `justification=centering` and/or `indentation=x.xcm` to your `\captionsetup`? You can also use the `subcaption’  package that comes with the `caption` package to place two figures besides each other and give them their own caption. Just read the manual of the packages.

Comment: Add `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`  to your preamble for global setup. Or before a `\caption{...` for a local setup/

Comment: @Beth Long  Besides the `\subcaption` package that comes with `caption` there is also the `floatrow` package that provides options to manipulate subfigures and their captions. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear, how caption should be centered:

- Thus all caption should have the same style or just this two in mini pages?
- How should be centered:

  - only last row in caption text or
  - complete caption?

In answer I Assume, that captions in this figure has own, from other captions different style.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=3cm]{geometry} % useful for page dimensions
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \captionsetup{justification=centerlast}
%    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a.png}
                \captionof{figure}{Constraints on visible dark photon decays}
                \label{fig:APrimeVisibleDecayConstraints}
            \end{minipage}%
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b.png}
                \captionof{figure}{Constraints on invisible dark photon decays}
                \label{fig:APrimeInvisibleDecayConstraints}
            \end{minipage}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with `\captionsetup{justification=centerlast}`:

[image]

with `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=3cm]{geometry} % useful for page dimensions
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.49]{example-image-a.png}
                \captionof{figure}{Constraints on visible dark photon decays}
                \label{fig:APrimeVisibleDecayConstraints}
            \end{minipage}%
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale=0.49]{example-image-b.png}
                \captionof{figure}{Constraints on invisible dark photon decays}
                \label{fig:APrimeInvisibleDecayConstraints}
            \end{minipage}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you only make OP MWE compilable ... and forgot on centering captions. Anyway +1!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want the captions of the figures to align with the y-axes of the figures. There are two options to achieve that. One is using the `subcaption` package (as I mentioned in my comment). The other is using the `floatrow` package, that is compatible with the `caption` package(s) and provides some powerful tools to manipulate figures, tables and captions.

In this MWE I have used both options. I did not use the `minipage` workaround as both options provide a better way to place two figures side by side.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin={25mm,25mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} % <= offers subfigure and subcaptions options
    \captionsetup{labelfont={bf,sf,small},labelsep=endash,box=colorbox,boxcolor=yellow!50,slc=off,textfont={color=blue},} 
    \captionsetup[sub]{labelsep=endash}
%   \DeclareCaptionSubType*[arabic]{figure}
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure \thefigure.\arabic{subfigure}}
    
\usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[figure]{floatrowsep=columnsep}

\setlength\columnsep{10mm}

\begin{document}
    
    Captions centered using \verb*|\subcaption{}| and \verb*|\subcaptionbox{}| :
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \captionsetup[sub]{width*=.4\textwidth,margin={8mm,2mm}}
        \subcaptionbox{Constraints on visible dark photon decay. \label{sfig:visible}}[.45\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{visible_dphoton_decay.jpg}}
        \subcaptionbox{Constraints on invisible dark photon decay. \label{sfig:invisible}}[.45\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{invisible_dphoton_decay.jpg}}
        \caption{Constraints on dark photon decay.} \label{fig:decay}
    \end{figure}
    
    The plots in figure \ref{fig:decay} show decay of visible dark photons (\subref{sfig:visible}) on the left and of invisible dark photons (\ref{sfig:invisible}) on the right.
    
    
    Captions centered using \verb*|floatrow| environment:
    
    
    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \captionsetup[sub]{width*=.4\textwidth,margin={8mm,2mm}}
        \ffigbox{
        \begin{subfloatrow}[2]
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\subcaption{Constraints on visible dark photon decay. \label{frfig:visible}}}
                {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{visible_dphoton_decay.jpg}}
            \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
                {\subcaption{Constraints on invisible dark photon decay. \label{frfig:invisible}}}
                {\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{invisible_dphoton_decay.jpg}}
        \end{subfloatrow}
        }
        {\caption{Constraints on dark photon decay.} \label{frfig:decay}}
    \end{figure}
    
    In figure \ref{frfig:decay} the same two dacays are present in \subref{frfig:visible} (visible) and \ref{frfig:invisible} (invisible).
    
\end{document}
```

This MWE results in the following PDF (Note that the figure captions still are using the whole linewidth of the figure float):

[image: Caption placement]

**Please note** the way refencing to the subfigures works now. Using the normal `\ref{}` option will give you a correct reference to the total figure, but will result in placing a number in front of the subfigure. To correctly refer to the subfigure use `\subref{}`. This behaviour is caused by redefining the `\thesubfigure` counter in the preamble. When you comment that line out and uncomment the line above it the subfigures are still counted in arabic, but without the prefix *Figure*.